# Scala Play Rest service cannot find Controllers in routes file [Play 2.6, Scala]

Tags: scala, routes, package

I have recently revisited a project I have not worked on in over a year. Yesterday I was able to successfully run the REST service with no problems. Today while I was refactoring the location of certain controllers in this project I started to encounter errors related to controllers could not be found within a given package.

My routes file that looks like this:

[image]

UserController is defined as such:
[image]

However; when trying to compile this project, I receive a list of errors like: (redacted most, only included one controller for sample)

```
type UserController is not a member of package com.jkdev.controllers
[error] POST       /users                                       com.jkdev.controllers.UserController.createUser
```

Additionally, my Binders are no longer being detected by the routes file as well, so I am seeing errors like: `[error] /Users/...../Developer/cashflows/metadata/conf/routes: object binders is not a member of package com.jkdev`.

Like I mentioned, yesterday this was working, so I tried reverting to that commit and rebuilding, but this issue persists.

I have attempted to delete all `target` directories and recompile, ran sbt clean; cleanFiles. All of which provided nothing of value.

Overall this feels like a build error; but I changed nothing about the build file so I have no idea where to look next

Comment: Do you see this error in IntelliJIdea or in plain command-line sb?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was:

I updated the intelliJ SBT preferences to use `sbt shell` for all builds,tests,runs, etc.
After deleting all of the `./target` directories, doing SBT compile and run did not reproduce the `target` directories for my projects.

After updating IJ SBT preferences to not use SBT shell for builds; I was able to re-compile w/ IJ and reproduce the `target` directories.

Doing `sbt run` afterwards successfully launches the server.